# Is there a SWING widget for a VU Meter like needle?

Tags: java, swing, widget

I am looking for a widget that would look like a needle that would move against a customisable arc background. Something along the lines of a VU meter as seen below:

[image: A VU meter screen]

Does anyone know of any non-commercial (aka $-free) SWING widget available like this?

Comment: I'd be looking in XxxGraphXxx (JFreeGraph, JGraph, Jung ....)

Comment: Java Swing component library "SteelSeries": http://harmoniccode.blogspot.com/2010/08/java-swing-component-library.html

Comment: JFreeChart has a "dial" style chart, maybe take a look at that: http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/images/DialPlotDemo2a.png

Comment: For [example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16163964/230513).