# JFreeChart - Adding more than one ChartPanel in the same JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jfreechart

I need to add two chartPanels in a same JPanel.

I did this for a single chartPanel, and it worked:

```
JPanel content = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
final ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart);
chartPanel.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(500, 270));
content.add(chartPanel);
```

But I tried to add the second chartPanel doing this:

```
   JPanel content = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,2));
   final ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart);
   chartPanel.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(500, 270));
   content.add(chartPanel);

   final ChartPanel chartPanel2 = new ChartPanel(chart);
   chartPanel2.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(500, 270));
   content.add(chartPanel2);
```

But when I do this, both graphs are displaying in a wrong way, like only a line or something, why this is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`ChartPanel`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/ChartPanel.html) constructor that lets you specify the preferred size, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7602126/230513). Alternatively, override [`getPreferredSize()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/230513), as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16182011/230513).

[image: image1]