# Java Swing JFreeChart DialPlot legend

Tags: java, swing, jfreechart

In a nutshell: how to add a legend to a `JFreeChart DialPlot`?

More specifically, my DiaPlot looks like this:
[image]

And I would like to indicate that values in [-100, 0] (red) range are "badluck" while values in [0, 100] (green) range are "goodluck".

Hence I'd like to add a legend to the `DialPlot` but unfortunately it seems that is doesn't have the `setFixedLegendItems()` method as other JFreeChart chart types do have.

Any idea / hint would be more than welcome.

Thanks!
Thomas

Comment: A complete example is examined [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16163964/230513).

Comment: Cross-posted [here](http://www.jfree.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=116937).

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `DialLayer`, such as [`org.jfree.chart.plot.dial.DialTextAnnotation`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/plot/dial/DialTextAnnotation.html). Update the annotation in your implementation of [`PlotChangeListener`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/event/PlotChangeListener.html). Related examples are seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16163964/230513) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13309587/230513).

Comment: Thanks a lot but I'm not sure to understand how I could create a legend based on these examples (i.e. a one-color box with a description next to it) as I understand that it only writes text. To be more specific, I'd like to have the setFixedLegendItems() functionality on a DialPlot (where the colors of the legend correspond to the green and red lines on the DialPlot). Is there any  approach to achieve this? Thx!

Comment: Not that I know. `DialTextAnnotation` is black, but you can change the text and color of an adjacent `JComponent`.