# JFreeChart DialPlot reduce title gap

Tags: java, swing, jfreechart

I have a JFreeChart DialPlot with a title:

```
JFreeChart chart = new JFreeChart("A title", aDialPlot);
```

I would like to reduce the vertical spacing between the dial meter and the title on top of it but I couldn't find anything in the API.

Any help or hint would be greatly appreciated !

Thanks,
Thomas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could leave the title off the chart, like they show [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16163964/261156):

```
JFreeChart chart = new JFreeChart(aDialPlot);
```

And put the title on top of a square chart:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
panel.add(new JLabel("A title"), BorderLayout.NORTH);
panel.add(new ChartPanel(chart) {
    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(300, 300);
    }
}, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```