# JFreeChart DialPlot tooltip

Tags: java, swing, jfreechart

What would be the simplest approach to add/customize a tooltip on a JFreeChart `DialPlot` (in a Java Swing application)?

While it is fairly straightforward to customize tooltips on other chart types (e.g. implement `CategoryToolTipGenerator` for category charts), I couldn't find any documentation on how to achieve this on dial / meter charts.

Many thanks for any hint!

Comment: What have you tried? Please show your effort and consider post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) reproducing your problem.

Comment: Well, my first question is: does JFreeChart offer this functionality (I couldn't find it in the JavaDoc). If not, what would be the best overall approach (e.g. add a transparent panel with a tooltip?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16163964/230513), the usual implementation of tooltips requires support for chart entities, which is not available in [`DialPlot`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/plot/dial/DialPlot.html). Because  `DialPlot` handles its own rendering, you might consider whether a [`DialLayer`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/plot/dial/DialLayer.html) could meet your requirement. `DialTextAnnotation` or `DialValueIndicator`, illustrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16163964/230513), may be suitable You could also implement your own `DialLayer`.

Comment: Thanks. I implemented now the following workaround: override the ChartPanel getToolTipText(MouseEvent evt) method.